# Can i assign tags to list items in orgmode?

Tags: org-mode

Is there a way to assign tags to list items and not just to headings? I can't seem to find anything relevant in the orgmode manual.

Comment: tags: no cf. the org syntax.  but you can use description lists.

Comment: i'm sorry, I don't get it could you please elaborate?

Comment: a description list is `- tag :: desc`,  but there's no `- desc :tag:`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Lists are intended to be very light and lack most of the features headings can have.  List entries can not have tags, keywords or properties.

Comment: pardon the ignorance, i'm completely new to orgmode (emacs as well!), but when you do a daily todo list, are you supposed to insert your items as  subheadings ? shouldn't headings consist of other stuff below?

Comment: That's how I do it. Each "todo" item is a headline with a "TODO" keyword. Checkboxes are useful for things that don't need any of the extra "stuff" headlines have. Grocery lists for example.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to put a tag-like message when exporting plain lists, you can define a macro like this:

```
#+MACRO: tag @@latex:\hfill{}\textsc{$1}@@ @@html:&#xa0;&#xa0;&#xa0;<span class="tag"><span class="$1">$1</span></span>@@
```

And use it:

```
* Heading with its real tag  :mytag:
  - Plain list item with its simulated tag  {{{tag(mytag)}}}
```

It is only useful to get a message similar to a tag when exporting to PDF/Latex or HTML, of course it is not a real Org tag.